# Unable to infer base url. This is common when using dynamic servlet registration or when the API is behind an API Gateway swagger 2.10.5

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, swagger, springfox

Trying to configure swagger 2.10.5 with spring boot Rest API but keep getting the error `Unable to infer base url. This is common when using dynamic servlet registration or when the API is behind an API Gateway`

Gradle

```
compile "io.springfox:springfox-swagger2:2.10.5"
compile "io.springfox:springfox-swagger-ui:2.10.5"

plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.3.1.RELEASE'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.9.RELEASE'
    id 'java'
}
```

**Config File**

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan
@EnableSwagger2WebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackageClasses = {
        Test.class
})
public class SpringFoxConfig {
    @Bean
    public Docket apiDocket() {
        return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
                .select()
                .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.any())
                .paths(PathSelectors.any())
                .build();
    }
}
```

**ApplicationFile**

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class MeroRentalRestApiApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MeroRentalRestApiApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

SpringFoxConfig and application are in the same package

Tried lot of the solution from the

https://github.com/springfox/springfox-demos/blob/master/boot-swagger/src/main/java/springfoxdemo/boot/swagger/Application.java

https://github.com/springfox/springfox/issues/2191

https://github.com/springfox/springfox/issues/1996

https://github.com/springfox/springfox/issues/1996

https://springfox.github.io/springfox/docs/current/

Comment: maybe try to use annotation `@EnableSwagger2`? or you could change dependency to a new swagger `org.springdoc:springdoc-openapi-ui`

Comment: @VasylSarzhynskyi I can't use EnableSwagger2 for version swagger 2.10.5. It doesn't contain.

Comment: This solve my issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62754998/whitelabel-error-page-swagger-this-application-has-no-explicit-mapping-for-err?noredirect=1#comment110978358_62754998

Answer (score -1):

If anyone is using 2.10.5 and facing same issue then in my case I was able to resolve it by adding below dependency springfox-spring-webmvc with same version(2.10.5). I already had springfox-swagger2 and springfox-swagger-ui dependencies in my pom.xml file.

I got clue from https://github.com/springfox/springfox/issues/3336