# Whitelabel Error Page Swagger, This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback swagger2:3.0.0-SNAPSHOT

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, swagger, springfox

Trying to configure swagger in spring boot 2.3.1.

**Gradle Config**

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url 'http://oss.jfrog.org/artifactory/oss-snapshot-local/' }
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-rest'
    testImplementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test') {
        exclude group: 'org.junit.vintage', module: 'junit-vintage-engine'
    }
    implementation "io.springfox:springfox-boot-starter:3.0.0-SNAPSHOT"
    compile('io.springfox:springfox-swagger2:3.0.0-SNAPSHOT')
    compile('io.springfox:springfox-swagger-ui:3.0.0-SNAPSHOT')
}
```

**Swagger Config**

```
@Configuration
@EnableSwagger2
public class ApplicationSwaggerConfig {
    @Bean
    public Docket employeeApi() {
        return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
                .select()
                .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.any())
                .paths(PathSelectors.any())
                .build()
                .apiInfo(getApiInfo());
    }

    //create api metadata that goes at the top of the generated page
    private ApiInfo getApiInfo() {
        return new ApiInfoBuilder()
                .title("Employee API")
                .version("1.0")
                .description("API for managing employees.")
                .contact(new Contact("Craig Golightly", "http://globomantics.com", "craig@globomantics.com"))
                .license("Apache License Version 2.0")
                .build();
    }
}
```

**Controller**

```
@RestController
public class TestController {
    @RequestMapping(value = "/HelloWorld", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String HelloWorld(){
        return "Hello World";
    }
}
```

**Application**

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class MeroRentalRestApiApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MeroRentalRestApiApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

**Error**

```
Whitelabel Error Page
This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.
Mon Jul 06 21:19:55 AEST 2020
There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404).
```

[image]

Here is the package reference
[image]

Comment: What about the `api-docs` endpoint? Is it available?

Comment: Same thing with the API-DOC http://localhost:8080/api/v2/api-docs

Comment: Is there a `server.servlet.context-path` property present? If so, try adding the context path to the Swagger urls you're attempting to visit.

Comment: @Michiel After adding  server.servlet.contextPath=/swagger-ui.html. I can see {
  "_links" : {
    "profile" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:8080/swagger-ui.html/profile"
    }
  }
}

Answer (score 13):

Able to solve the problem

Remove the below dependency

```
compile('io.springfox:springfox-swagger2:3.0.0-SNAPSHOT')
compile('io.springfox:springfox-swagger-ui:3.0.0-SNAPSHOT')
```

Remove the swagger 2 anotation

```
@EnableSwagger2
```

The navigation URL is http://localhost:8080/swagger-ui/index.html

Reference
https://github.com/springfox/springfox/issues/3070

Comment: Solved my problem too.

Comment: So glad I came across this answer.  I was trying to navigate the UI on http://localhost:7000/swagger-ui.html instead of http://localhost:7000/swagger-ui/index.html

Comment: Thanks, in my case I had to add @Profile ("swagger"), to the config.

Comment: For me it's working without removing @EnableSwagger2. Same result if I remove it too!

Answer (score 3):

In spring boot it works by simply adding this, no other dependencies needed:

```
<dependency>
 <groupId>io.springfox</groupId> 
<artifactId>springfox-boot-starter</artifactId>
 <version>3.0.0</version> 
</dependency>
```

The url is /swagger-ui/

Comment: That's no different from the previous answer.

Comment: In spring boot it works by simply adding this, no other dependencies needed:
<dependency> <groupId>io.springfox</groupId> <artifactId>springfox-boot-starter</artifactId> <version>3.0.0</version> </dependency>
The url is /swagger-ui/

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow! It seems you have given some useful information in your comment. If you would please move that into your answer, then remove the part of your answer which is the same as [Bossit's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64450250/453435), and mention that your answer builds on Bossit's, then this answer will be much higher quality and won't be closed as a duplicate

Answer (score 1):

Adding these 2 dependencies in my pom.xml solved the problem

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.2</version>
        </dependency>
```

hope it may help someone

Answer (score 0):

If you are using swagger 2 in that case the url is updated.

`Old url :` http://localhost:8080/swagger-ui.html/

`New url :` http://localhost:8080/swagger-ui/index.html

Add these two dependency to your pom for swagger 2 if you are using spring boot.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
    <artifactId>springfox-boot-starter</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

and

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
    <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Reference : https://www.baeldung.com/swagger-2-documentation-for-spring-rest-api